# Start css radial gradient 40% from the top

Tags: css, gradient

I have radial gradient like this at the moment:

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center left, rgb(${colours.blue}), rgb(${colours.darkBlue}));
```

it starts in the center, but I'd like it to start 40% from the top, something like this works in chrome, but doesn't work in firefox (both latest)

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at top 40% left, rgb(${colours.blue}), rgb(${colours.darkBlue}));
```

Bits like `rgb(${colours.darkBlue})` are just importing strings like `'255, 255, 255'`

Comment: have you added '-webkit-gradient' and '-moz-linear-gradient' as well?

Comment: Shouldn't be neccesary @YaserAdelMehraban

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban handled by autoprefixer I use, yes

Comment: @Ilja Would this new answer work for your problem?

Comment: The correct syntax for the first is *left center*. But most browser will accept it like this. The correct syntax for the second is *left 40%* . Don't use **top** here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has a [history](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY78zKntDQAhVEVhoKHejnBvwQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F18059878%2Fradial-gradient-not-working-in-firefox&usg=AFQjCNGEbznKeolc29Co2hpM5mRsJVw9wg&sig2=ssT6MgGOYpFjq-7OVnffNQ&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d2s) of [bugs](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY78zKntDQAhVEVhoKHejnBvwQFggtMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8110720%2Ffirefox-radial-gradient-issue&usg=AFQjCNHam3dNG_TpAplnx8TQi6vsbmbmAA&sig2=R4a7Eb5InL4laUFRZqgWqw&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d2s) with `radial-gradient()`. But i've found a possible solution on [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient)

```css
div {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 0% 30% , #FF0000 0%, #0000FF 50%);
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Tested in Firefox and Chrome, both produces the desired result, to invert the effect (bottom-right corner), just take the opposite variables:

```css
div {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 100% 70% , #FF0000 0%, #0000FF 50%);
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control percentage like this:

```
background-image: radial-gradient(blue 40%, darkblue 60%);
```

you can also use webkit and moz for additional support. See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v8crqy99/1/

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired result.